# duplicating div background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a small website that is one page with 5 stacked divs within the body. The first and second div are fine but all the divs after that(3, 4, and 5) all repeat the unique background image when the site is viewed in IE9. The site works fine in FF 20.0.1, IE10, IE 10 compatibility, and IE9 compatibility so this issues appears to only show up in IE9. I have taken everything out of the CSS and html except for just those 5 containers and find that I can't pinpoint the issue causing the background images to duplicate in the 3rd, 4th, and 5th div. I've also repeated the second div and it also duplicates the background in the second instance. If anyone has any insight as to what I am missing I would greatly appreciate it. 
Also, I have played with no-repeat and other ideas I found while searching for a solution but nothing has worked for me at this point.

CSS:

```
* {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Myriad, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
a {
    color: #60789c;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #60789c;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
body {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
div#content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 900px;
}
div#SectionOne {
    Background-image: url(../images/section1.jpg);
    height: 707px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#SectionTwo {
    Background-image: url(../images/section2.jpg);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 1159px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#SectionThree {
    Background-image: url(../images/section3.jpg);
    height: 668px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#SectionFour {
    Background-image: url(../images/section4.jpg);
    height: 1385px;
    width: 100%;
}
div#SectionFive {
    Background-image: url(../images/section5.jpg);
    height: 1165px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="content">
<div id="SectionOne">

</div>

<div id="SectionTwo">
<a name="SectionTwo" />


</div>



<div id="SectionThree">
<a name="SectionThree"/>

</div>

<div id="SectionFour">
<a name="SectionFour"/>



</div>

<div id="SectionFive">
<a name="SectionFive"/>


</div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mv6hY/)

Answer (score 0):

Close your `a` tags like this `<a name="SectionXXX"></a>` rather than this `<a name="SectionXXX" />`

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="SectionOne">
    </div>
    <div id="SectionTwo">
        <a name="SectionTwo"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="SectionThree">
        <a name="SectionThree"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="SectionFour">
        <a name="SectionFour"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="SectionFive">
        <a name="SectionFive"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All I can suggest with what you've posted is that you change `Background-image` to `background-image` ... but that's a long shot.

Also your `<a>` elements are incomplete; and the `name` attribute is out of date now. Use IDs instead. That is, if you want to link to one of those divs, use this:

```
<a href="#SectionFive">Go to Section Five</a>
```

Then just get rid of those `a`s in the divs altogether.

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks Ralph and to everyone else who looked over my question.